# Solving wcf error after wpf publish

Tags: wpf, wcf, deployment, httprequest

I have a wpf application that consumes a wcf service and it works fine, but when i publish the application and run it. Throws me "a property with the name 'httpRequest' is not present". i believe the application is not finding the wcf service, but only after publishing, I don´t know what to do!

Comment: A code sample would be helpful here so that we can see what you've tried and what might be going wrong.

Comment: Just when i try to consume de service the error is thrown

Comment: SIIAA_Service.Service1Client ws = new SIIAA_Service.Service1Client(null,"", "");

ws.Ejecutar(this.XML().InnerXml);

Comment: Why are you passing in null for the first parameter and blank strings for the last two?  Just use `new SIIAA_Service.Service1Client();`.

Comment: sometimes i send data there, and sometimes i dont. eitherway it doesnt fix my problem